# Change a command in \l@chapter at the middle of the document

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

I am using `\l@chpater` to rotate the entry of `\chapter` in toc, but I need that on even pages of the toc the chapter name is on the left of the page, and in odd pages of the toc the chapter name in the right.

```
\documentclass[openany,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\def\Rotatebox#1{\rotatebox[origin=lB]{270}{#1}}
    
    \newcounter{linhas}
    
    
    \def\paginapar{\noindent\hspace*{.7\textwidth}\rlap}
      
    \def\paginaimpar{\noindent\llap}
    
    
    
    
    
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand\l@chapter[2]{%
    \smash{\paginapar{\box{%
       \protect\Rotatebox{\protect\parbox{\thelinhas\baselineskip}{\titulo\def\numberline##1{##1  } \centering #1 \vspace*{3pt}\rule{\thelinhas\baselineskip}{1pt}}}}%
      \protect}}}
     
    
    
    \makeatother


\begin{document}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{linhas}{4}}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Foo chapter}
\section{Foo section}
\section{Foo section sdf}
\section{Foo section sdf}
\subsection{Foo subsec}
\subsubsection{Foo subsecsec}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{linhas}{10}}
\chapter{Foo chapter}
\section{Foo section}
\section{Foo section sdf}
\section{Foo section sdf}
\section{Foo section}
\section{Foo section sdf}
\section{Foo section sdf}
\section{Foo section}
\section{Foo section sdf}
\section{Foo section sdf}
\subsection{Foo subsec}
\subsubsection{Foo subsecsec}

\end{document}
```

So, I want to change `\paginapar` by `\paginaimpar`, maybe indirectly using `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\somecommand}`

Comment: your example doesn't compile.

Comment: ohh, I see now, \usepackage{graphicx} is missing

Comment: Don't guess if your example is working or not. Copy it in a new document and *test* it.

Comment: strange, it is working for me, tested in overleaf using LuaLatex as compiler

Comment: sorry no. This doesn't compile. Check if overleaf shows an error (the red circle) and check the log-file.

Comment: When you say on the right (or left) of the page, you mean on the right or left margin? Problem in any case: the rotated box   will not break across pages.